# Strategy Tester Exit Always Re-Enters

Tags: pine-script

I have the below code in the strategy tester and when it auto-exits during the take profit at 300 it always enters again. How do I stop it from re-entering when an exit triggers

```
isShort=false
isLong=false

if (goLong)
    if(isShort==false)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,100000,when=isShort?false:true)
        strategy.exit("b1","Long",profit=300)
        isShort:=true
        isLong:=false

else
    if(isLong==false)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short,100000,when=isLong?false:true)
        strategy.exit("b2","Short",profit=300)
        isShort:=false
        isLong:=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **History Referencing Operator** `[]` when you want to access a variable's previous value.

You can think that for every new bar in pine-script, your code gets re-executed. So, what happens is, you set `isShort` and `isLong` to `false` at the beginning of your code, every time. So, it doesn't matter if you change them later in the code. For the next bar, your code gets re-executed and `isShort` and `isLong` gets the value `false` right at the beginning.

What you need to do is, simply re-assign their old values to those variables after the declaration. In this way, you declare your variables first, then assign their last values from previos bar/execution to them.

```
isShort=false
isLong=false

isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)
```